# Everything in the scene except the player looks blurry when the camera is moving | Unity2D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I started off my game using a simple camera follow script which only followed my player on the x axis with an offset and and some restrictions

I recorded a video on my android to show what I mean. In the recording the issue is a bit exaggerated ( due to recording) and only viewable once the spikes enter the view. When not recording, the player animation is perfectly smooth. [Here's the video](https://vimeo.com/249590519)

```
using UnityEngine;

 public class MainCamera : MonoBehaviour {

     public Transform target;
     public float xOffset, xPosRestrictionMin, xPosRestrictionMax;

     private float yPos, zPos;

     void Start ()
     {
         yPos = transform.position.y;
         zPos = transform.position.z;
     }

     void LateUpdate ()
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x + xOffset, xPosRestrictionMin, xPosRestrictionMax), yPos, zPos);
     }
 }
```

However when first running the game everything looked "jittery". Despite all my player physics being inside fixed update, input inside update and camera updates being inside lateupdate. I tried setting interpolate to extrapolate on the players rigidbody2d. Now the player would look and animate smoothly but everything else look blurry when the camera is moving. I thought that maybe my script or settings were at fault so I tried to turn off vsync, set target frame rate to 60 and when nothing worked I downloaded Cinemachine. Even with cinemachine instead of my own script it still looks blurry and I can't figure out why. Here's a simplified version of my controls.

```
 private void Update()
 {
     //Handle touch input
     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
     {

         foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
         {
             switch (touch.phase)
             {
                 // Touchdown
                 case TouchPhase.Began:
                     if (onGround || !doubleJumped)
                     {
                         jump = true;
                         touchReleased = false;

                         if (onGround)
                             anim.SetBool("jump", true);
                     }
                     break;

                 //Touch up
                 case TouchPhase.Ended:
                     allowGlide = false;
                     anim.SetBool("glide", false);
                     if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
                         touchReleased = true;
                     break;
             }

         }
     }
 }


 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(newMoveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

     onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
     if (onGround && !jump)
     {
         gliding = false;
         allowGlide = false;
         anim.SetBool("glide", false);
         anim.SetBool("jump", false);
         doubleJumped = false;
     }

     //Slowly Accelerate if not at top speed and touching the ground
     if (newMoveSpeed < moveSpeed && onGround)
         newMoveSpeed += 0.0165f;
     anim.speed = Mathf.Clamp(newMoveSpeed, 13, 18);

     //Jumping 
     if (jump && onGround)
     {
         jump = false;
         rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
     }
     else if (jump && !doubleJumped && !onGround)
     {
         jump = false;
         doubleJumped = true;
         allowGlide = true;
         rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
     }

     //Add multiplier if falling down
     if (rb.velocity.y < 0 && allowGlide)
     {
         anim.SetBool("glide", true);
         if (!gliding)
         {
             rb.velocity -= Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y;
             gliding = true;
         }
         else
         {
             rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (glideMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
         }
     }
     else if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
     {
         rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
     }

     //Increase fall multiplier if touch is released mid jump
     else if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && touchReleased)
     {
         rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
     }
     else if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
     {
         return;
     }
 }
```

Thanks, any help or feedback is appreciated!

Comment: i didn’t see any ‘blurry’ that you talk about but know that you’re ray casting every frame which may hinder to your performance

Comment: I dont see any blurring either, thats how its supposed to look when things move

Comment: Share your player movement script please - it could be the movement of the player is not smooth, so the camera jumps, resulting in the jerky background.

Comment: @mad.meesh i'm not raycasting every frame, only when the screen is touched

Comment: @Lestat I don't think you're right, other games look a lot smoother

Comment: @MisterMagoo I already shared the movement script, it's the bottom script part

Comment: @Baxorr unless i’m missing something, you’re calling `Physics2D.Overlapcircle` in your fixed update .. which is a ray cast operation... every fixed update ... ie possible more than once per frame...

Comment: but with that being said.. it may not be a performance issue

Comment: @mad.meesh oh sorry, I didn't actually realize that that was a raycast operation. Is there a better way to do a ground check? I did however check the frame rate on my android device and it caps out at 30fps

Comment: @Baxorr np. and depending on what exactly you need, there may be a better way. if all you want to know is which animation to play based on the player’s position relative to the ground... then try something along the lines of checking to see if your player’s `transform.position.y` is `>` than the `y` (`+- a threshold value`) of your ground. this is only an idea and one of many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the frame rate of your game running on device? I have a film/animation background (but new to Unity) and it looks to me like you have a frame rate issue. Although, if the recording software changed the graphics at all I'm not sure I am seeing the same thing you are. Why does your recording software do that? Have you tried using Rec? It works great for me.

Sorry for not posting this as a comment - my current rep won't allow me to.

Comment: I just checked. The frame rate on my android device is capped at 30 for some reason. That does seem to be the issue though. I tested the frame rate on pc and it looks very smooth and with a frame rate of 120+ fps. Setting it to 60 is also smooth, but I can't seem to change the frame rate cap on android

Comment: I would agree that that does seem like your issue. I don't know how to resolve that or if it's even possible. My guess is it depends on the device. Maybe you can get around it by changing the design of the moving objects in your game, or making them move slower. I understand that might not be a viable option. Maybe these pages will help:
http://www.paladinstudios.com/2012/07/30/4-ways-to-increase-performance-of-your-unity-game/

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

This link explains what seems to be forcing (or trying to force) a frame rate. I suggest you try that if you haven't already.

Comment: Since frame rate may be your issue, I would certainly appreciate you marking one of my comments as the answer so I can boost my reputation and post more comments :) if you feel like that's appropriate of course

Comment: I don't know what I had messed with but resetting the quality and player settings (under edit -> project settings) and setting the default android quality settings to high fixed my issue! The frame rate was no longer 30 but jumped up to 60 and now everything looks really smooth! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i think this is causing issues with the recording in the device which maybe took some computation power and caused issues, does this same thing happens while just playing and not recording?

Comment: Yes the same thing happens when not recording. I think it's because it's a somewhat fast paced game and my android device caps the frame rate at 30